# Webapp - User Account Management

Tags: authentication, firebase, user-accounts, stormpath

I'm working on a webapp that requires user account management and authentication. The users should be able to login to their account using different tokens - Email, Phone Number, Facebook id, Company account id etc. Same user might be using all of these different methods based on the entry point they choose to login.

From the backend, I should be able to retrieve the correct user account based on any of these tokens. Basically, multiple tokens (email, phone, facebook etc) should point to the same user account.

I have been looking into Firebase and Stormpath. From your experience, do you think Firebase or Stormpath are good options for me? I was wondering if there are good pre-build web solutions for this without re-inventing the wheel by myself.

Please feel free to suggest different web solutions and architecture tips.

Thanks for your time,
Iranga

Comment: Hi there, I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), and I can explain how we're complementary to Firebase.  But it would be helpful if you could tell us what you men by "different tokens", and what types of tokens you're referring to?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @robertjd, thanks for the reply. Different tokens means user names or login ids. Example: user's email address, phone number, facebook id, etc. A user will have one or more login ids. I should be able to query their account from the backend regardless of the id they use. You can think of as a hashmap with multiple keys to the same value (Keys: ids, Value: user account). Hope that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)

Firebase is a platform/ecosystem for building web/mobile applications, and as such they offer an authentication and authorization solution.  Building your app with them will require buy-in to their entire platform.

Stormpath is an authentication and authorization service that can be added to any type of application, regardless of where it is ran, where it is hosted, or what your fronted of backend is written in.  Our API does allow you to manually link different types of accounts together, e.g. password-based accounts or social accounts.  See [Modeling Your User Base](https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/accnt_mgmt.html#modeling-your-user-base) in our documentation.

We’re adding some support to make this easier and you can follow the [Account Linking](https://stormpath.ideas.aha.io/ideas/IAM-I-32) feature to know when this is available.

In sum: if you want an entire platform for your application, Firebase may be a good fit.  If you prefer to maintain more control over your hosting (such as using Heroku to deploy your Nodejs application and have Postgres available), then Stormpath would be the better fit.

Comment: Thanks for the response @robertjd. Account linking is the one I was looking for.